# Change icon on input and remove former icon (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input field and I want to display icons depending if there are any data in the input fields or not (warning if no data, check icon if the input field is populated)

My code is:

```
$(".input-icon").blur(function(){
  if($(this).val()) {
    $(this).before('<i class="fa fa-check text-complete left-info"></i>');
  } else {
    $(this).before('<i class="fa fa-warning text-warning left-info"></i>');
  }
});
```

So the issues I have is:

1. I want to display the icons when the user loads the page if there are existing data
2. If the field has data it will show a check icon, but if the data is removed from the field, it will show both icons on each other, I want to destroy the other icon and only show one.

I tried with creating the icon on change and a empty() within the if statement but instead got my input field removed and not the icon.

Comment: you have to remove old icon first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search for the `i` element and remove it.

```
$(this).siblings('i').remove();
```

in jQuery there are many different selectors and functionality to find the element(s) you need. In your case, it should be `siblings`, as your icon is at the same level as your input.

Another way would get a reference to the `parent` element.

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
parent.find('i').remove();
```

Fyi best practice is to save the reference of `$(this)`.

```
$(".input-icon").blur(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  self.siblings('i').remove();
  if(self.val()) {
    self.before('<i class="fa fa-check text-complete left-info"></i>');
  } else {
    self.before('<i class="fa fa-warning text-warning left-info"></i>');
  }
});
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Works as intended!

Answer (score 0):

before method insert specified content to your selector. try this code.

```
$(".input-icon").blur(function(){
  if($(this).val()) {
    $(this).before('<i class="fa fa-check text-complete left-info"></i>');
  } else {
    $('i', this).remove();
    $(this).before('<i class="fa fa-warning text-warning left-info"></i>');
  }
});
```